# Google Classroom - Getting Started

Tags: google-classroom

I am just getting started with the google classroom api. I signed up for the developer test accounts and have 1 teacher account and 2 student accounts. I created a couple of classes and enrolled the 2 students in the classes. I want to use the api either via .NEt or Javascript. The prerequisuites state that I need a Google Apps for EDU account with Google Classroom enabled. How do I get this? Also, I assume without having the Google Apps for EDU account I cannot perform the first step: 
"a) Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click Continue, then Go to credentials." 
When I perform this step when logged in under the teacher account I get an error: 
Error
"Developers Console has not been activated for your account. Your account may be suspended or disabled. If you are a Google Apps user, ask your domain administrator to enable Apphosting Admin on your account."

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a [Google Apps for Education](https://www.google.com/edu/) account, you have to register your domain (or buy one), and fill up this [form](https://www.google.com/a/signup/u/0/?enterprise_product=GOOGLE.EDU#0).
When filling the form, you will get information about the requirements needed to get the account.

To create a project in the [Developer Console](http://console.developers.google.com), you can do it even from your gmail account. After you created the project, you can enable the Classroom API so you application can access it.

When you run the code, you will have to login with a valid account (teacher or student). If you try to access the API with an invalid account you will get an error.

You can also use the Classroom API methods in the documentation. For example the resource [curses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list#try-it) has a "try it" section, where you can try the API before creating any project. There you can see how it works.

Comment: Thanks. This helps and I am on my way. I was able to get the courses for a student.